# How to improve the accuracy of the test set of LRCN-based video classification model

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, image-recognition

[An existing LRCN-based video classification model](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Action-Recognition) consists of resnet152 provided by torchvision and an LSTM layer, and this model achieves 92% accuracy on the UCF-101 test set.

The input range of this model is between [-1 ,1], now I want to use this model to classify another data loader loaded with data in the range of [0, 255]， so I retrained the model on the UCF-101 dataset using the new data loader, and after some rounds the accuracy of the training set reached over 80%, but the accuracy of the test set was only about 5%.

I tried not to use the resnet152 pre-trained model provided by torchvision, but started training from scratch, but the accuracy of the test set still did not increase.

How should I improve the accuracy of my model on the test set?